# Assign different color to each plt.step line

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a code which draws lines for the teams according to their tournament position in each game week.
Pretty much I managed to make it work, except 2 things:

1. For some reason a 4th (violet) line is drawn (teams are only 3) which goes from the top to the bottom throughout each game week. As I found out this line is drawn for every iteration (for each team) when plotting the lines. But why?
2. Lines are drawn from x = 0 starting point, thus not aligning with the points (which are drawn correctly). Lines should be drawn from x = 1 starting point as well (according to their Game_week value).
   Output:

[image]

What have I missed?

Example of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['Team1', 1, 1],
                   ['Team1', 2, 2],
                   ['Team1', 1, 3],
                   ['Team1', 5, 4],
                   ['Team1', 1, 5],
                   ['Team2', 2, 1],
                   ['Team2', 3, 2],
                   ['Team2', 4, 3],
                   ['Team2', 4, 4],
                   ['Team2', 3, 5],
                   ['Team3', 3, 1],
                   ['Team3', 4, 2],
                   ['Team3', 3, 3],
                   ['Team3', 2, 4],
                   ['Team3', 2, 5]
                   ], columns=['Team', 'Position', 'Game_week'])

positions = df['Position']
weeks = df['Game_week']
teams = df['Team'].unique()
print(teams)

# Coordinates:
y = positions
x = weeks
print(y)
print(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Labels:
plt.xlabel('Game weeks')
plt.ylabel('Positions')
plt.xlim(-0.2, 5.2)
plt.ylim(0.8, 5.2)

# Inverting the y-axis:
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

# x, y ticks:
xi = list(np.unique(x))
yi = list(np.unique(y))
plt.xticks(xi)
plt.yticks(yi)

# Colors for teams:
colors = {'Team1': 'tab:red', 'Team2': 'tab:blue', 'Team3': 'blue'}

# Points:
plt.scatter(x, y, s=45, c=df['Team'].map(colors), zorder=2)

# Lines between points:
for i, (team, l) in enumerate(df.groupby('Team', sort=False)):
    plt.step(list(zip(l['Game_week'], l['Position'])),
             '-',
             color=colors[team],
             linewidth=8,
             alpha=0.2, zorder=1)
    print('step:', i, '; team:', [team])
    print(l)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues is with the `plt.step()`, where you are using `zip`. As per documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/step_demo.html), you just need to give the x and y values. Updating that line as below...

```
for i, (team, l) in enumerate(df.groupby('Team', sort=False)):
    plt.step(l['Game_week'], l['Position'], ## No zip
             '-',
             color=colors[team],
             linewidth=8,
             alpha=0.2, zorder=1)
```

.. will give you this plot. Does this meet your needs? You may want to change xlim to start at 0.8 perhaps.

[image]